# Split string by comma in BigQuery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, bq

I would like to split a string in the BQ row into other rows by comma. But I need to split only in case if it is just a comma without space. As of now, I use, for example,

```
SELECT SPLIT('Mon,Tue,Wed', ',')
```

but If I have *'Mon, 23,Tue,Wed, 25'* I would like to see results

```
Mon, 23
Tue
Wed, 25
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe this is achievable with regex functions. Try adding `regex` tag to the question.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to use regex like `re.split(r',(?!\s)', x)` and for dataframe it is work, but not for BQ

Answer (score 3):

Maybe replace `,`  to something else (like `*`) before split and then replace it back?

```
select array_agg(replace(splitted, '*', ', '))
from unnest(split(replace('Mon, 23,Tue,Wed, 25', ', ', '*'))) as splitted
```

[image]